# Flask redirecting PUT request, getting ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: python, flask

I have an API endpoint that updates a database.  What I want is to update the database, then redirect to `/requests` with a flash message.  Here is the PUT endpoint that updates the database:

```
@requests.route('/<request_id>', methods=['DELETE', 'GET', 'PUT'])
def one_req(request_id):
    if (request.method == 'PUT'):
        req = ChangeRequest.query.get(request.form['request_id'])
        req.state = request.form['state']
        try:
            db.session.commit()
        except:
            flash('There was an error updating the request.', 'error')
        else:
            flash('The request has been ' + request.form['state'].lower() + '.', 'success')

    return redirect(url_for('requests.index'))
```

Here's the endpoint I'd like to redirect to:

```
@requests.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT'])
def index():
    if(request.method == 'GET'):
        requests = db.session.query(ChangeRequest, Project).filter(...).all()
        return render_template('requests.html.jinja', requests=requests)
```

For completeness, here's the Javascript that makes the PUT request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: `/requests/${data.request_id}`,
    data,
    type: 'PUT'
})
```

The redirect isn't working.  The request is a PUT, so that's what get's redirected to  `requests.index`.  I have some questions to help me understand what's going on:

1. How can I change this to a GET request instead?
2. Even if I capture a PUT in `requests.index` (e.g., by changing the first line of `requests.index` to `if(request.method == 'GET' or request.method == 'PUT):`), I see the following in the Javascript console:  `PUT http://txslibvpda1v.nss.vzwnet.com:5001/requests/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)`.  The template does not re-render.  How can I achieve the behavior I am looking for?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked if the request to index is actually a GET? The client might or might not change the request type upon 302. And if the request type isn't GET, index() doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by returning a success indicator to the Javascript function:

```
    if (request.method == 'PUT'):
        req = ChangeRequest.query.get(request.form['request_id'])
        req.state = request.form['state']
        try:
            db.session.commit()
        except:
            flash('There was an error updating the request.', 'error')
        else:
            flash('The request has been ' + request.form['state'].lower() + '.', 'success')
            data = { c.name: str(getattr(req, c.name)) for c in req.__table__.columns }
            return jsonify(data)
```

In the success handler of the put request, I closed the modal & reloaded the page.  The flash messages persist through the reload:

```
        $.ajax({
        url: `/requests/${data.request_id}`,
        data,
        type: 'PUT',
        success: res => {
            $('#requestModal').modal('hide')
            location.reload()
        }
    })
```